# In-depth explanation of the multinomial Bayes classifier

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

I am new to machine learning and am trying to understand the different classifiers. I have searched the internet and books for a comprehensive explanation of the Multinomial Bayes classifier, but I just cannot seem to understand it.

First, I would like to know in which cases the multinomial distribution can be used. Do I understand correctly that it is mainly used for qualitative features (so not boolean or numeric)?

Second, I do not understand the equation for the conditional probability. The formula provided on the Wikipedia site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier under **Multinomial naive Bayes** is not comprehensive to me. What does pki stand for?

Comment: Just in case this question gets no response, one might try the [statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com).